# Stop 'favorites' contacts showing in 'recents' section as well

Tags: iphone, contacts, ios, multitasking

I've done some searching around, but haven't found anything.  Basically, I have set several contacts as 'favorites' on my iPhone (6) and have enabled 'favorites' and 'recents' to show in the in-app multitasking view.  The issue I have is that some of the contacts I have nominated as 'favorites' are also showing in my 'recents' section, so I'm effectively doubling up.  I was just wondering if it is possible on iOS 8 to prevent this from occurring i.e. if a contact is nominated as a favorite, do not show it in the 'recents' section.

Comment: Recent is recent, there is no selection on that.

Comment: @Buscar웃; it just strikes me as odd that Apple wouldn't have thought of this potential duplication.

Comment: It is not really duplicate. Recent and Favorite are not same thing, and it is not a duplicate entry anyway, just same one showing up in more then one place.

Comment: @Buscar웃; from the multitasking view it's a duplication of contacts, although this duplication isn't conveyed in the contacts thankfully.  I understand the difference between recents and favorites, but they are both there to serve the purpose of quick access to contacts, so why would I want to waste space with two of the same contacts?  Perhaps this is a feature for iOS 8.3/9.

Comment: perhaps.......... :)

Comment: @Buscar웃SD hopefully the improvements of this (http://ios9guide.com/latest-concept-video-illustrating-on-working-mechanism-of-notification-center-of-ios-9/) video will come to fruition!